# How to grant URI permission in PhoneGap build app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Environment: This is the only cross-platform app I've worked on. I did not build it. It's about 5 years old. Targets: Android 4.4 and above, iOS is not limited. I'm developing on a Mac, using Phonegap Build- specifically 3.7.0. I am getting this error on my Android emulator- API 23 and 19.

I am trying to access imageURI to check for file size. My `FileTransfer` limit is about 10 mb. Here is my code for that:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURI(this.pageContainer.items.items[0].imageURI, function(fileEntry){
                fileEntry.file(function(fileObj){
                     if (maxSize <= fileObj.size){
                          Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Chosen image is too large. Submit a different image.");   
                          return;
                      }
                      else {
                          Ext.Msg.alert("You are here:", "file size accepted "+ fileObj.size);
                       }
                  })
            })
```

Problem is that it's unable to get down past `resolveLocalFileSystemURI`. The adb log says:

```
E DatabaseUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1A03-
3B0B%3ADCIM/Camera/elevation.jpg from pid=2921, uid=10080 requires
android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

I know that you can add this permission to AndroidManifest, and go from there, but I am actually just using the PhoneGap build 3.7.0. I have to edit `config.xml`, which is currently using these settings:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="pgb" spec="0.3.2" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="pgb" spec="0.2.12" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="pgb" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="pgb" spec="0.5.0" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="pgb" spec="0.3.10" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="pgb" 
spec="0.2.12" />

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="orientation"      value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen"       value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
```

Previously, I did not include the `<feature>`, but in an attempt to remidiate added it to my config.xml which resulted in no change in behavior. What do I need to add to my `config.xml` to do the same as MANAGE_DOCUMENTS?

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? What platform are you developing on? Windows, MacOS? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: I've added the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to upgrade my PhoneGap Build version to cli-5.2.0 (among other versions, I'm sure). My build was too old to support granting Android access to the file when coupled with my Android target of 19+.